# Run scripn by name from spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sppreadsheet with many rows, in each row - cell with status in second column for example: a010111101001 and about 30 more statuses. In scripts I have functions named the same like status cell. All I want is one function, that call all other functions based on active status cell. Now I have only function, that get name of the script from active cel, and will be very grateful if you can help me. Here is code that i have:

```
function nameoffunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123')
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var status = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  //value from status - is the name of function
  //I search way to do something like this:
  //run.scrpt(status);
}
```

Update:
In status variable - value "a00110000000000000"

```
function a00110000000000000(){
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123')
  var result = ss1.getRange("C35");
  result.setValue(22)
}

function nameoffunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123')
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var status = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var a = {
    "u2": function(){return status;},
    "as": function(){return "eft";}
          };
Logger.log(a["u2"]());
}
```

Update: Thank you @daniel !
The way to run scripn by name from spreadsheet cell is:

```
function nameoffunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123')
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var status = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var a = {
    "a00110000000000000": function(){
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123')
  var result = ss1.getRange("C35");
  result.setValue(22)
    },
    "as": function(){return "eft";}
  };
Logger.log(a[status]());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is this:

- On one cell, create a [in-cell drop down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en) of all your function names
- Create a [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) function to handle value change.
- In your event handler, check if [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) is the cell with the drop-down list.
- Check the value and execute the appropriate function.

Easy to call function without using `switch`:

To define functions:

```
  var a = {
    "u2": function(){return "abc";},
    "u1": function(){return "eft";}
  };
```

To call a function by name (example):

```
Logger.log(a["u2"]());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but im not sure that I understand correctly: How I can call script with name from "status" variable? I try to write status instead of abc, but nothing happend and funktion under name from status doesnt work.. Please see the update, what I do wrong?